# JOIN in MySQL and relational tables error

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables, "food","member" and "member_food". I'm trying to make an update user page where a collection of  tags are prepopulated by the data in "member_food".

I have debugged the ID sending from the previous page which allows me to select the entry I wish to query, `ID:4`.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `food` left join `member_food` on food.entityid = member_food.food_id WHERE member_id = '$id'";
            //Breakfast
            $breakfastresult1 = $mysqli->query($query);

echo '<select name="breakfast1">';
        while($BreakfastData1 = mysqli_fetch_array($breakfastresult1, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
            echo '<p><option value="' . htmlspecialchars($BreakfastData1['member_food.food_id']) . '">' 
                . htmlspecialchars($BreakfastData1['member_food.food_name']) 
                . '</option>'
                . '</p>';        
        }
echo '</select>';
```

However, the select fields appear to be empty. I think it's not pulling the correct values from my leftjoin table.

Here is an example of my member_food table: 
[image]

food table:

[image]

Comment: `leftjoin` space that out => `left join`

Comment: thanks @Fred-ii- still empty though.

Comment: This `['member_food.food_id']` and `['member_food.food_name']` shouldn't contain `member_food.` - Could be part of the problem.

Comment: ^^^ Doing this didn't do anything? ^^^

Comment: Sorry Fred, had a lot of answers at once and i didn't see. No it didn't. Thanks though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit this, first you have a typo (space missing in left + join) second you need to tell from which of the table member_id belong

```
     $query = "SELECT * FROM `food` as f left join `member_food` as mf on f.entityid = mf.food_id WHERE mf.member_id = '$id'";
```

Comment: *"space missing in left + join"* - OP did fix it. Reload the question.

Comment: Okay @Fred i have one more thing in answer , do you think it is right? we seem to be friend on SO :p

Comment: Let's wait for the OP to respond. ;)

Comment: Hey guys, i've been at this project for about 8 hours today so i'm trying to finish this bit up as I'm complete MUSH! 

with your query, I'm confused as to why I need to do `member_food` as mf ?

I've also updated OP

Comment: it is alias a temporay name for your table so you can shortly use it for refrence as a "table" . and than call colomn name with dot

Comment: No Abdul it didn't. for reference: $query = "SELECT * FROM food left join `member_food` on food.entityid = member_food.food_id WHERE member_food.member_id = '$id'"; I'm sure I have done it wrong

Comment: using your query didn't do anything for me :( sorry

Comment: run your query in phpmyadmin and tell what error you are getting

Comment: SELECT * FROM food left join member_food on food.food_id = member_food.food_id WHERE member_food.member_id = 4 Seems to have fixed it! Thanks :)

Comment: @BradlySpicer I know it's been solved, but you had `food.entityid` in your question, where technically should have read as `food.entity_id` unless that's another typo.

Comment: @BradlySpicer Ah ok. Just checking ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to plan your joins correctly. And, as Abdul pointed out, typos are bad ;)

[image]

Comment: Hey Andrew, Currently using: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/ at the moment :)